# Puppet + Passenger + Apache/Nginx

Tags: ruby, apache, nginx, passenger, puppet

I'm working on a very large puppet deployment, but seem to be hitting a brick wall.  My ideal setup is to use Nginx + Passenger to serve puppet.  The problem I am having is that Puppet throws errors when running through passenger.  If I start puppetmasterd, everything works fine, but serving through Passenger gives the following errors:

```
Jun 22 07:33:04 $master_hostname puppet-master[15710]: Starting Puppet master version 2.6.8
Jun 22 07:33:04 $master_hostname puppet-master[15720]: No support for http method POST
Jun 22 07:33:04 $master_hostname puppet-master[15720]: Denying access: Forbidden request: $client_hostname($client_ip) access to /report/$client_hostname [save] authenticated  at line 0
Jun 22 07:33:04 $master_hostname puppet-master[15720]: Forbidden request: $client_hostname($client_ip) access to /report/$client_hostname [save] authenticated  at line 0
```

Everything seems to point to an auth.conf problem, but my auth.conf file is about as generic as it could get, and like I said, everything works when I serve puppet using Rack directly.

Has anybody ever ran into this issue?

Comment: This question might be better off on [SF].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this:

http://groups.google.com/group/puppet-users/browse_frm/thread/910994e88f21a497/cae809c17a9acd8a?#cae809c17a9acd8a

The concept being that you need to configure NGINX to pass information through to Puppet as it now provides the SSL layers.